# How to make a comparison between prices saved as text in DB and HTML form using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

In my mySQL db, under `price` I have values like x.xxx as text. for example 3.000, 4.350, 18.400 and so on.

In my HTML form I have some values like

```
<option value="4.000">4000 €</option>
<option value="5.000">5000 €</option>
<option value="6.000">6000 €</option>
```

and when I submit I use `cast(price as signed)` to make a `<=`  comparison.

Sometimes, the result is not correct, as I tried to understand is when there is not a round price saved in DB like 5.360 instead of 5.300

I guess by changing this with something I do not know, it will be fixed.

What do you suggest me for a solution?

```
if (!empty($price)) $conditions[] = "cast(price as signed) <= '".mysql_real_escape_string($price)."'";
```

Comment: Please share your full code

Comment: @SajithNair I placed the code for the price

Comment: cange the field to be a decimal instead of varchar

Answer (score 0):

Should this work? 5.360 treat as 5.3

```
$conditions[] = "FLOOR(cast(price as signed),1) <= '".mysql_real_escape_string($price)."'";
```

If you want 5.360 to be 5.4 (round up) use:

```
$conditions[] = "ROUND(cast(price as signed),1) <= '".mysql_real_escape_string($price)."'";
```